# Dividing parts of an array and using them to solve static equilibrum eqs

Tags: arrays, matlab

So I have a text file, I read it into matlab using `textscan` now I have a big array that I need to divide into smaller arrays or matrices so I can use the numbers given to solve static equilibrium equation and find support reactions.

This is my code for scanning it in

```
function [C]= read_input(input)


   fid = fopen (input);
   C = textscan(fid,'%s', 'Delimiter', '\n', 'CommentStyle', '#');
   C = C{:};
   fclose(fid);
```

I get this as my C array

ans =

```
'2 1'
'0.0 1.0 1.0'
'5.0 3.0 0.0'
'11.0 3.0 2.0 -9.0'
'0.1 3.0 1.0 1.0'
'0.0 1.0 1.0'
'10.0 4.0 -2.0 9.0'
'1.0 1.0 1.0'
'1.0 1.0 1.0'
'1.0 1.0 1.0'
'0.0 1.0 0.0'
'0.0 1.0 1.0'
'1.0 1.0 0.0'
'F 1.0 6.0 -7.0'
'F 4.0 1.0 1.1'
'F 1.0 8.0 1.0'
'F 6.0 1.0 0.0'
'M 0.0 9.0 1.0'
'M -1.0 1.0 0.0'
```

and this was my original txt file

## number of external forces and moments

2 1

## coordinates of the points at which external forces are applied

## x y z

0.0 1.0 1.0
5.0 3.0 0.0

## magnitude and direction of external forces

## F dx dy dz

11.0 3.0 2.0 -9.0
0.1 3.0 1.0 1.0

## location at which external couple moments are applied

## x y z

0.0 1.0 1.0

## magnitude and direction of external couple moments

## M ux uy uz

10.0 4.0 -2.0 9.0

## location of supports

## x y z

1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
0.0 1.0 0.0
0.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 0.0

## type (F/M) and direction of reaction

## type dx dy uz

F 1.0 6.0 -7.0
F 4.0 1.0 1.1
F 1.0 8.0 1.0
F 6.0 1.0 0.0
M 0.0 9.0 1.0
M -1.0 1.0 0.0

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I guess I didnt really ask one, how can I divide that C array into different matrices or something like that?

Comment: Yeah so how do you want to divide it?

Comment: How the original text file is divided so I can use the locations and magnitudes of the different forces and moments to calculate support reactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about this. Either you input as string cell array and then convert to number or you directly input as numbers.

1> Getting data from cell array has to be individual as variable length and different quantities wouldn't let you enter at one go.

```
temp = str2num(C{1,1}); 
num_forces= temp(1);
num_moments = temp(2);
```

2> I would prefer going about it by inputting in as numbers as given in [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/reading-arbitrary-format-text-files-with-textscan.html)

```
input_text = textscan(fid,'%s', 1,'delimiter','\n'); % Read header line
HeaderLines{1}=input_text{1};
input_text = textscan(fid,'%f %f',1,'delimiter','\n');
[num_forces,num_moments] = input_text{1,:};
```

This would make your code larger but much more manageable.

Comment: Will that go through each line of the text file and pull out the numbers I need?

Comment: No you have to go through each line individually and pull out the numbers according to what you need.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: it will automatically shift the pointer and you again do a textscan. Follow the example I gave. Also if you think this answers your question, please marked as answered.